# Save FORM edits when closing html files

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I have an offline html file on my desktop, I intend to open it in the browser and then edit a TEXTAREA, When I click the browser save button, Form data is not saved in Chrome, but it is saved in Firefox if I save all files (css,js,jpg etc) but not when I save it as a single html file.

Is there a way to force the browser to save edited form data when it is closed in browser, and possibly to keep it as a single html file

Answer (score 0):

You could save it in a cookie or in a session, but it will only save in the browser you saved it in the first place.

Your best bet is to store a variable in the file in Javascript.

Something like this:

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var saved_text = "";
$('#text_area').val(saved_text);
$('#submit_btn').click(function(){
 saved_text = $('#text_area').val();
});
});
```

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="text_area"></textarea>
<input type="button" id="submit_btn"/>
```

Youd have to also save the document after this so that the saved text variable persists once you close it

Comment: Umm, but I won't be seeing the textarea content saved next time I open the file with JS, or is possible?